# sanitize_text_field and apostrophe problem

Tags: wpdb, sanitization

I've written a custom plugin to send data via a form to a personal database, different from the WP one. Everything is working fine except the fact that when you write a name, for example *D'ALESSANDRO*, it's saved as *D\'ALESSANDRO*.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**

It seems that adding `stripslashes_deep()` before `$_POST` is working.

```
$custom_field = sanitize_text_field(stripslashes_deep($_POST[custom_field]))
```

**Can this be unsafe?**

This is how I'm sending data to database:

```
$custom_field = sanitize_text_field($_POST[custom_field])
if ( count($reg_errors->get_error_messages()) < 1) {
    $userdata = array(
    ........
    'id_locality'   =>  $custom_field
    ........
    );
    $where_data = array(
      .......wherefield...........
    );
    $pldb = new wpdb('user', 'pwd', 'db', 'localhost');
    $update_table = $pldb->update('table',$userdata,$where_data);
```

I need to save data into the database without the "\", I can't sort this when printing it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `stripslashes()` function after reading the data it will remove the extra slashes.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. You mean, save data with salshes into the database, and then use stripslashes() when printing data to the php page? In this case, I can't do this, for various reasons data has to be saved in the database directly without the extra slashes.

Comment: To explain, I can send data to this database also via another form which uses htmlpurifier, and it's saving data into the database without the slashes, I need data to be saved in the same way.

Comment: Noticed that the other form also uses $this->db->escape, it's a codeigniter function. I need to do things like this with a wordpress form, is this possible?

Comment: Post updated with possible solution!

Comment: In my opinion, its safe as stripslashes only remove those slashes that are being used to escape the special characters and stripslashes_deep does the same thing for each element